# Gnome-packagekit-data install error

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, raspbian, gnome

I am in a bad state with Debian on my Pi, where I can no longer sudo apt-get install anything without error. For example

```
 $ sudo apt-get install autogen
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 autogen : Depends: guile-2.0-libs but it is not going to be installed
           Depends: libopts25-dev (= 1:5.18.4-3) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: autogen-doc but it is not going to be installed
 gnome-packagekit-session : Depends: gnome-packagekit-data (>= 3.14.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

And i get: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1). Full log:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  coinor-libcbc3 coinor-libcgl1 coinor-libclp1 coinor-libcoinmp1 coinor-libcoinutils3 coinor-libosi1 cups-bsd cups-client epiphany-browser-data fonts-opensymbol gconf-service gconf2-common gsfonts gsfonts-x11 gstreamer0.10-alsa
  gstreamer0.10-plugins-base jackd libabw-0.1-1 libavahi-gobject0 libboost-date-time1.55.0 libcdr-0.1-1 libclucene-contribs1 libclucene-core1 libcmis-0.4-4 libcolamd2.8.0 libe-book-0.1-1 libeot0 libepoxy0 libetonyek-0.1-1 libevdev2
  libexttextcat-2.0-0 libexttextcat-data libfm-data libfm-extra4 libfm-gtk-data libfm4 libfreehand-0.1-1 libgconf-2-4 libgif4 libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring0 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-0 libgtop2-7
  libgtop2-common libhsqldb1.8.0-java libhyphen0 liblangtag-common liblangtag1 libmenu-cache-bin libmenu-cache3 libmng1 libmotif-common libmozjs185-1.0 libmspub-0.1-1 libmtdev1 libmwaw-0.3-3 libmythes-1.2-0 libodfgen-0.1-1
  liborcus-0.8-0 libpciaccess0 libqt4-dbus libqt4-xml libqtcore4 libqtdbus4 libraptor2-0 librasqal3 librdf0 librevenge-0.0-0 libvisio-0.1-1 libvte-common libwnck-3-common libwnck-common libwpd-0.10-10 libwpg-0.3-3 libwps-0.3-3
  libxcb-util0 libxfont1 libyajl2 lp-solve lxmenu-data lxpanel-data netsurf-common pi-package-data python3-gi qdbus qtchooser qtcore4-l10n uno-libs3 ure xfonts-100dpi xfonts-encodings xfonts-utils
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gnome-packagekit-data
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnome-packagekit-data
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 54 not upgraded.
208 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,302 kB of archives.
After this operation, 8,041 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 114514 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-packagekit-data_3.14.0-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-packagekit-data (3.14.0-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-packagekit-data_3.14.0-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/mimetypes/application-x-catalog.png', which is also in package pi-package-data 0.2
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-packagekit-data_3.14.0-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

The issue has to do with 'gnome-packagekit-data' and I see similar complaints online: https://www.google.com/search?q=gnome-packagekit-data+raspberry+pi+error+site:www.raspberrypi.org&num=100&espv=2&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjA5-HswJXTAhVSImMKHdk1AsUQrQIIJygEMAA&biw=1279&bih=771 but no solutions.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work for me, although I don't know if it has any destructive consequences, so proceed with caution!

The problem for me with this this issue was pi-package. It was interfering with gnome-packagekit. The fix for me was to remove pi-package, pi-package-data, and pi-package-session. Note that you have to use dpkg to remove the packages so that apt won't complain.

```
sudo dpkg -r pi-package pi-package-data pi-package-session
```

After that command competes, you should be free to run:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I don't know if this causes any other problems, but I assumed it doesn't because dpkg didn't say any packages depended on it.